# How to display only main menu (without submenu) in Django-CMS?

Tags: django, django-cms

How to display only main menu (without submenu) in Django-CMS?

I try:

```
{% show_menu %}
```

but this display also submenu

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the number of levels for the [menu to traverse](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/2.4.2/getting_started/navigation.html#show-menu):

```
{% show_menu 0 0 0 0 %}
```